# Server kernel upgrade

Tags: 12.04, server, database

What are the implications of a database server that hasn't been restarted for a while. The last restart was in July, and am I being over cautious that something will break when I restart it? We do not have a failover db.

I see that under `/usr/src`, the latest kernel downloaded was `3.2.0-99-generic`

When I do a `uname -a`, the kernel displayed is `3.2.0-51-generic`. Will it automatically update when I restart it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server that does not start on reboot has serious problems =)

Kernel updates require a reboot, and from what you described, it sounds as if a new kernel has been installed and by default Ubuntu will boot the most recent kernel when you reboot.

You can check this by looking at the kernels listed in /boot and/or at the grub menu (/boot/grub/grub.cfg)

There is no reason to suspect rebooting into a new kernel will cause problems, but if it does post back.

Comment: Will try it after-hours. Need to make sure nothing goes wrong on this one. Tried it on another VM and it worked fine.

Comment: How often does linux download updates in the folder /usr/src? Or was it a manual setting by the previous sysadmin here!

Comment: Ran pretty smooth. I used 
        A)       sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty 
        B)       Then list old kernels using
       dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)
        C)       Then cleaned old kernels to get space back using                                                                                                                                                                    sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic     (keep one old kernel, remove all others using this command multiple times)

Answer (score -2):

Why would it update automatically? Did you install something or have startup scripts that force an update? Otherwise, no it won't. Also, just create a backup. There are live CD/USB's that can help you out without the need to even start the server. Clonezilla for example.

http://clonezilla.org/

Good luck!